# Decrypt a a middle chunk of data using pycrypto AES or other algorithm

Tags: python, pycrypto

I was looking for a way to use an encryption algorithm from pycrypto package that allows me to encrypt an original LARGE piece of data, and then decrypt only a MIDDLE chunk of this data. In other words, start decrypting the data at a certain offset, instead of starting to decrypt it at offset 0.

I've tried AES, as you can see below. But, it only allows me to properly decrypt the data if I go from beg of the enrypted data to the part I really need to decrypt, instead of just decrypting a middle chunk of data (of course with the proper key), and skip decrypting parts before this middle chunk. This is important in saving time and processing power. Let's say you have an original data that is 4GB. At some point in time, you only need the data from offset 3GB-3.5GB. Decrypting a whole 2GB of data to get to the 1GB chunk that you need is a waste of time and resources...

Is this the nature of all encryption/decryption algorithms? Perhaps you can recommend something that does what I want? That works with a key and is pretty secure..

```
    from Crypto.Cipher import AES

key = '0123456789abcdef' #16 chars
mode = AES.MODE_CBC

e = AES.new(key, mode)

orig = 'hellohowareyousuhellohowareyousu' #32 chars
print len(orig)

a = e.encrypt(orig)
print len(a)

d = AES.new(key, mode)

#works
print d.decrypt(a[:16]) #aes requires encrypt/decrypt 16 chars at a time
print d.decrypt(a[16:])

#doesn't work
print d.decrypt(a[16:])
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using [CBC (ciphertext block chaining)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Cipher-block_chaining_.28CBC.29) mode, in which the message is split up into blocks and the output of one block used to encrypt the next. This is fundamentally a sequential operation; to decrypt, you must also work through the ciphertext sequentially.

If you use [CTR (counter)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_modes_of_operation#Counter_.28CTR.29) mode, you can have random access.

Comment: @MistahX ECB mode is incredibly insecure.  Never use it.  Look at the penguin images here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECB_mode